# What font could I (semi) accurately substitute for L'Oréal's?

Tags: font-identification, font-recommendation

I'm looking for a font that resembles the typical "L'oréal" font:

[image]

Some recommendations I've found that seem to resemble the font are:

- [ITC Blair](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/blair/) from ITC, and
- [Trade Gothic Extended](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/trade-gothic/extended/), from Adobe.

Unfortunately ITC Blair is £320 (admittedly for 12 fonts), and Trade Gothic Extended is £30. The first is far out of my budget for the use-case and the latter is more than I'd like to have to pay for the project itself.

The purpose is to take a fun, but unflattering, picture of a group of us and reproduce the "we're worth it" connotations as a Christmas card for those three of us in the group.

This will be put together using Gimp (on Ubuntu 18.04), and the recommended font would, ideally, be available for either low-cost (limited personal use) or free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A free one, [Syncopate](https://www.1001fonts.com/syncopate-font.html) from 1001fonts.com

[image]

You can search in [1001fonts.com](https://www.1001fonts.com/wide+sans-serif-fonts.html?page=14&items=10) using as tags `wide` `sans serif`

[image]

---

[Capoon](https://www.fontspace.com/m%C3%A5ns-greb%C3%A4ck/capoon-personal-use) from fontspace.com (free)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it’s pretty close; I won’t accept an answer for a couple of days but you have my appreciation and an up-vote.